# Select query to show duplicates with max date

Tags: mysql, select, duplicates, max

I've researched this question, but I'm still struggling to write a query that works. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Table

```
+----------+-------------+
| username | signup_date |
+----------+-------------+
| user1    | 2010-01-15  |
| user1    | 2010-02-15  |
| user2    | 2010-03-15  |
| user3    | 2010-04-15  |
| user3    | 2010-05-15  |
| user4    | 2010-06-15  |
| user5    | 2010-07-15  |
| user6    | 2010-08-15  |
| user6    | 2010-09-15  |
| user6    | 2010-10-15  |
+----------+-------------+
```

I want to write a query that returns just duplicate username values and the most recent signup_date.

Desired Results

```
+----------+-------------+
| username | signup_date |
+----------+-------------+
| user1    | 2010-02-15  |
| user3    | 2010-05-15  |
| user6    | 2010-10-15  |
+----------+-------------+
```

So far I have this, but it doesn't filter down to the max of signup_date. Instead it returns every duplicate row.

```
SELECT users.username, users.signup_date
FROM users 
INNER JOIN (SELECT username FROM users
GROUP BY username HAVING count(id) > 1) dup ON users.username = dup.username;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an aggregation (no join is needed):

```
select u.username, max(u.signup_date)
from users u
group by u.username
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Thank you!! Exactly what I was looking for. Figured the answer was likely simple. Amazing to get a response so quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT username, MAX(signup_date)
FROM users
GROUP BY username
HAVING COUNT(username) > 1
```